# How i can split a string in more substrings in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I'm new to qt I want to know how I can split a string into substrings with one or more operation. 
This is an example

```
QString FileName = "ABCD_1234_5678.exe";
```

I want this output or substrings: "ABCD" "1234" "5678"`

The QString in my application represents the name of a file that I have read with `QDir::entryInfoList`

Comment: Use `QString x = "ABCD_1234_5678.exe"; QString y = x.left(4); // remove ".exe" QStringList output = y.split("_");`

Comment: Qt has great documentation you know: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html should help split the extension off the path in `Qt`.

Comment: You might consider using regular expressions: `QRegExp` or `QRegularExpression`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
QString FileName = "ABCD_1234_5678.exe";
QString FileNameWithoutExtention = FileName.split('.')[0];
QStringList SubStrings = FileNameWithoutExtention.split('_');
qDebug()<<SubStrings;
```